# retrieving what swing radio button is selected from a group

Tags: java, swing, validation, jbutton, jradiobutton

User selects either the Admin radio button or the User radio button (2 of which are contained in a group). If admin radio button is selected the user is brought to the adminDashboard, else the user is brought to the userDashboard.

I have been looking for code to validate which radio button is selected although I can't find any correct java code

**my current button and listener method code** (trying to use isSelected())

```
    JButton btnEnter = new JButton("Enter");
    btnEnter.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() 
    {
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) 
        {
            if(rdbtnAdminAccount.isSelected())
            {
                AdminDashboard admin = new AdminDashboard();
            }
            else if (rdbtnNormalAccount.isSelected())
            {
                UserDashboard userd = new UserDashboard();
            }

        }
    });
```

**radio button and group code:**

```
    JRadioButton rdbtnNormalAccount = new JRadioButton("Normal Account");
    rdbtnNormalAccount.setBounds(361, 190, 109, 23);
    contentPane.add(rdbtnNormalAccount);

    JRadioButton rdbtnAdminAccount = new JRadioButton("Admin Account");
    rdbtnAdminAccount.setBounds(361, 213, 109, 23);
    contentPane.add(rdbtnAdminAccount);

    accountGroup.add(rdbtnNormalAccount);
    accountGroup.add(rdbtnAdminAccount);
```

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). 2) `rdbtnNormalAccount.setBounds(361, 190, 109, 23);`  Use layouts (layout padding, borders etc.) for a robust GUI!

Comment: It's very confusing for you to mention finding "correct" jQuery code in a question about Java.  jQuery is a JavaScript library (JavaScript is unrelated to Java).

Comment: Don't use a `MouseListener` on `JButton`, use an `ActionListener`

Comment: Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Buttons](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html)

Comment: I agree with @MadProgrammer. Using MouseListener is mainly only for things like JPopupMenu, clicking/dragging/double clicking/mouse actions dealing with the screen. The RadioButton is best used with ActionListener, as is all other forms of buttons.

Comment: thanks for the input regarding ActionListener and buttons. My code is working at the minute so I will go through it later and change MouseListener sections for best practice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### You Could...

Add all your buttons into a `List` of some kind and simply iterate over the list to find the selected button...but then you need some way to determine what action to take...

This could be solved by using a `Action` mapped to the `JRadioButton` in some kind of `Map`...

Basically...

```
for (JRadioButton btn : listOfButtons) {
    if (btn.isSelected()) {
        Action action = mapOfActions.get(btn);
        action.actionPerformed(new ActionEvent(e, ActionEvent.ACTION_PERFORMED, null));
        break;
    }
}
```

You don't HAVE to use `Action`, it's just what is readily available..

### You Could...

Create a method that takes a variable list of arguments of `JRadioButton` that simply returns the selected radio button, but you still have to make a decision about which button it is...see first point...

### You Could...

Just keep doing what you're doing...